# Laravel 4 translation by country

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I need help I'm working on a project that needs to translate the language of the site automactically depending on the country the user is from. I've never done this before so please any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This process is known as *localization*, also known as *i18n*. Laravel provides this functionality natively. Have a look at the [official docs](http://laravel.com/docs/localization) for instructions on getting started.

EDIT:

The developers of Laravel [made a deliberate decision](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/2023) to **not** host a central localization repository for Laravel 4. You might snoop around to see whether other users have forked localized translations, but given the relative newness of Laravel 4, I doubt you'll see much out there. If you can't find the translation you need, you may want to make a fork of Laravel and build out your own localization file using `en` as a template.

Comment: I was looking at that and I was wondering where do I get the langauge files from because laravel only come's with en?

Answer (score 1):

Right, as was pointed out before, there is this [repository](https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel4-lang).
In which you can find common translations for many languages. It is well maintained, take a look!